# Spring Data REST: force openapi schema export

Tags: spring-data-rest, openapi-generator, springdoc

When working with SDR, I need that the associated resources are expanded in the returned JSON. I have achieved this by adding @RestResource(exported = false) to the associated resource. For example:

```
@NotNull
@RestResource(exported = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Client client;
```

So far so good, as I can read and write to the association without extra requests.
The problem is that I use openapi-generator to create feign clients of the API, and this case the Client entity is not exported in the openapi schema, so I need this workaround to get it exported:

```
public Client getClientInline()
{
    return client;
}
```

I'd like to know if is there any way to get rid of this workaround. I made a test with an excerpt projection, but the schema also doesn't get exported. Adding @SchemaProperty also doesn't helps.

This is the current schema output:

```
"EntityModelIntegrationConfig": {
"required": [
"client",
"cron",
"enabled",
"template"
],
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"id": {
"type": "string",
"format": "uuid",
"readOnly": true
},
"cron": {
"type": "string"
},
"enabled": {
"type": "boolean"
},
"templateInline": {
"$ref": "#/components/schemas/Template"
},
"clientInline": {
"$ref": "#/components/schemas/Client"
},
"links": {
"type": "array",
"items": {
"$ref": "#/components/schemas/Link"
}
}
}
}
```

The expected behavior is to have client and template to be treated as properties, so I can remove the additional "inline" getters.

Thanks in advance